# Fix a bi-lingual wrong right to left text

Tags: ms-word, right-to-left

I hope I can explain the problem correctly!
There is a document contains some sentences in both Persian/Arabic and English in Word which is basically written in "left to right" direction and it is shown correctly because the original author has placed the words manually in correct positions. the image below may describe better:
[image: In this Image the problem has been explained]

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to fix this automatically. The settings marked in a green V are correct, and that's what the document should have, but you'll probably have to move text around manually.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [this blog article](http://marc.durdin.net/2012/08/mixing-rtl-and-ltr-plaintext-vs-html.html) which talks about this problem within MS Office products. The treatment of mixed `LTR` and `RTL` text actually comes from a mismatch in how plain-text and HTML parsers handle the data.

In essence, it has to do with how the parser makes its assumptions about whether the text is primarily `right-to-left` or primarily `left-to-right`.

In MS Word, when you click on the <kbd>Align Left</kbd> or <kbd>Align Right</kbd> buttons, you essentially strip out formatting which is already there, and apply block-level formatting to the paragraph itself.

It looks like your document was primarily written in `RTL` text, with some `LTR`-based English words thrown in. Unfortunately, based on your system settings, when you hit the <kbd>Align Left</kbd> or <kbd>Align Right</kbd> buttons, the individual Paragraph you are editing probably gets shoved into `LTR` English-mode, which will do *exactly* what you are seeing: shift the English words around, and treat each `LTR` *phrase* as if it were a `RTL` *word* - which makes the ordering go crazy.

One possible solution, while editing this kind of document, might be to look at the `LTR` and `RTL` mode options for MS Office. Here are a few resources that might help you, depending on your version of Word:

- [Working with RTL Languages in Word (Office 2007 and Earlier)](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/keyboards/winrtl.html)
- [Bidirectional Features in Microsoft Word](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2010/03/04/bidirectional-features-in-microsoft-word.aspx)
- [How to Type in my Language using Office 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_global_experience/archive/2009/08/17/how-to-type-in-my-language-using-office-2010.aspx)

I hope this helps!